# '_remove_dead_weakref' error when updating scikit-learn on Win10 machine

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm new to open source so appreciate any/all help. 
I've got notebook server 4.2.3 running on: Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit) on my Windows10 machine. 
When trying to update scikit-learn from 0.17 to 0.18, I get below error which I believe indicates one of the dependency files is outdated. I can't understand how or why since I just (<1 month ago) installed Python through anaconda. Note I get the same error when I try 
conda update scikit-learn 
conda install scikit-learn=0.18
pip install -U scikit-learn

ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'

How do I fix it? Should I try to uninstall and re-install? If so what's the safest (meaning will cleanly remove all bits) way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to update to 0.18. I'm running

Answer (score 2):

After spending a couple hours to no avail, deleted the python anaconda folder and reinstalled. Have the latest bits now and problem solved :)